# Mostrar información de un ArrayList

Tags: java, poo

Clase Contacto

```
package com.cmc.entidades;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Contacto {

// Atributos
private String cedula;
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private Direccion direccion;
private ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos;

// Metodos

public Contacto() {

}

public void agregarTelefono(Telefono telefono) {
    telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();

    telefonos.add(telefono);
}

public void mostrarTelefonos() {

    Telefono telf = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) 
        telf = telefonos.get(i);
        if (telf.getEstado() == "C")
        {
        System.out.println(telf.getTipo() + " - " + telf.getNombre());

    }
}

// Cosntructor
public Contacto(String cedula, String nombre, String apellido) {
    super();
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;

}

public void imprimir() {

    System.out.println("****" + nombre + " " + apellido + "*******");
    if (this.getDireccion() != null) {
        System.out.println(
                "Direccion: " + this.direccion.getCallePrincipal() + " y " + this.direccion.getCalleSecundaria());
    } else {
        System.out.println("No tienne asociada una direccion");
    }
}

// Getters && Setters

public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(String cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public Direccion getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(Direccion direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
    return telefonos;
}

public void setTelefonos(ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
    this.telefonos = telefonos;
}

}
```

Clase Telefono

```
package com.cmc.entidades;

public class Telefono {

// Atributos
private String nombre;
private String tipo;
private String estado;

// Constructor
public Telefono(String nombre, String tipo) {

    if (nombre != null && tipo != null) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        if (this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Movil") && this.nombre.length() == 10
                || this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("Convencional") && this.nombre.length() == 7)
            this.estado = "C";
        else
            this.estado = "E";
    } else {
        this.estado = "E";
    }

}



// Getters & Setters

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

}
```

Clase Main

```
package com.cmc.test;

import com.cmc.entidades.Contacto;
import com.cmc.entidades.Telefono;

public class TestMostrarTelefonos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Contacto contacto=new Contacto("1714616123","Carmen","Estrada");
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", "Convencional"));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", null));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("0992920306", "Movil"));
    contacto.agregarTelefono(new Telefono("2375467", "convencional"));
    
    
    contacto.mostrarTelefonos();
    

}

}
```

Resultado que me brinda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que nos debe dar es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

> En la clase `Contacto`: Agregar el atributo `telefonos`, del tipo
> `ArrayList` de `Telefono`, con los getters y setters respectivos. Crear un método `agregarTelefono`, que no retorna nada, recibe un `Telefono` y lo agrega a la lista de teléfonos. Crear un método `mostrarTelefonos`, que
> no retorna nada, no recibe nada y muestra en consola todos los
> teléfonos ingresados con el formato que se indica en resultado
> esperado.

**La parte superior ya está resuelta.**

Ya estoy por terminar un ejercicio, pero en el método `mostrarTelefonos` se debe mostrar los pertenecientes al estado `C`, ¿cómo logro hacer este paso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el método agregarTelefono(Telefono telefono) de la clase Contacto, estas creando un nuevo ArrayList cada vez que agregas un nuevo teléfono. Esto hace que guardes solo un teléfono, el último que ingresaste.

```
public void agregarTelefono(Telefono telefono) {
  telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();  // eliminar esta linea
  telefonos.add(telefono);
}
```

La instanciación del ArrayList debe ir en los constructores de la clase Contacto (en todos)

```
public Contacto(String cedula, String nombre, String apellido) {
  super();
  telefonos = new ArrayList<Telefono>();  //así
  this.cedula = cedula;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.apellido = apellido;
}
```

En el método mostrarContacto() hay algunos problemas de sintaxis, faltan los {} para el for y la comparación de los strings es mejor usar *equals()*

```
public void mostrarTelefonos() {
Telefono telf = null;
for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) 
    telf = telefonos.get(i);
    if (telf.getEstado() == "C")  // usar equals
    {
    System.out.println(telf.getTipo() + " - " + telf.getNombre());
    }
}
```

Mi versión

```
public void mostrarTelefonos() {
   Telefono telf = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < telefonos.size(); i++) {
       telf = telefonos.get(i);
       if (telf.getEstado().equals("C")){
       System.out.println(telf.getTipo() + " - " + telf.getNombre());
       }
    }
}
```